# How to map exting table to a model in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have mysql table named casa that have a primary key named casa_id.
I setted up a model:

```
 class Casa extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'casa';
public $casa_id;
public $anuncio_id;
public $banheiros;
public $capacidade_garagem;
public $dormitorios;
public $piscina;
public $preco;
public $dir_id;
public $cep;
public $numero_fotos;
public $visualizacoes;
public $ativo;
public $descricao;

public $timestamps = false;

protected $connection = 'eloquent_db';


}
```

Executing this code

$casa = \App\Casa::find($id);

I get his error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'casa.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `casa` where `casa`.`id` = 238 limit 1)

I don't know Eloquent but I assume that some conventioin is missing. Can you give the directives to map my existing table to a model so that I can use Eloquent. I am more of database first guy but I'm learning web api and don't want to deviate from my path and start writing SQL commands. My table columns have the exact names of my model.

code for the operation I want to perform:

```
$casa = \App\Casa::find($id);
$casa->dormitorios = 5;
$casa->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
class Casa extends Model{
  protected $table = 'casa';
  protected $primaryKey = 'casa_id';
  protected $connection = 'eloquent_db';
  public    $timestamps = false;
} 

$casa = \App\Casa::find($id);
```

Comment: My problem now is that I can't update the table. No exception is thrown, it just doesn't get updated.

Comment: @Diego Alves But what do you define in all fields in model?

Comment: I only updated a single property. Is there a problem?

Comment: @Diego Alves Sorry, I answered on first question. P.S. think, should read more  docs.

Comment: I found the answer the table columns must be specified as an array.   protected $fillable = array('anuncio_id' ... 'descricao'); It worked like magic.

Comment: @Diego Alves But for why you are making it? If table has the name name, except primary id? It will work without `protected $fillable` - like on my code above.